# How to avoid elasticsearch duplicate documents

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

How do I avoid elasticsearch duplicate documents?

The elasticsearch index docs count (20,010,253) doesn’t match with logs line count (13,411,790).

[documentation:](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html)

```
File input plugin. 
File rotation is detected and handled by this input, 
regardless of whether the file is rotated via a rename or a copy operation.
```

nifi:

```
real time nifi pipeline copies logs from nifi server to elk server. 
nifi has rolling log files.
```

logs line count on elk server:

```
wc -l /mnt/elk/logstash/data/from/nifi/dev/logs/nifi/*.log
13,411,790 total
```

elasticsearch index docs count:

```
curl -XGET 'ip:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty'
docs.count = 20,010,253
```

logstash input conf file:

```
cat /mnt/elk/logstash/input_conf_files/test_4.conf
input {
file {
path => "/mnt/elk/logstash/data/from/nifi/dev/logs/nifi/*.log"
type => "test_4"
sincedb_path => "/mnt/elk/logstash/scripts/sincedb/test_4"
}
}
filter {
if [type] == "test_4" {
grok {
match => {
"message" => "%{DATE:date} %{TIME:time} %{WORD:EventType} %{GREEDYDATA:EventText}"
}
}
}
}
output {
if [type] == "test_4" {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "ip:9200"
index => "test_4"
}
}
else {
stdout {
codec => rubydebug
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use fingerprint filter plugin: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-fingerprint.html

> This can e.g. be used to create consistent document ids when inserting
>   events into Elasticsearch, allowing events in Logstash to cause
>   existing documents to be updated rather than new documents to be
>   created.